# Does it make sense to map an object to another object of the same type?

Tags: c#, wcf, automapper

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and sending the results of my queries out of a WCF service. If I try to send out the entities returned by the queries, I get an exception due to the dynamic proxies.

My previous workaround for this was to use code like this...

```
return PatientServiceLogic.GetAll()
  .Select(p => new Patient {
    ID = p.ID,
    FirstName = p.FirstName,
    Surname = p.Surname,
    AccidentDate = p.AccidentDate
  })
  .ToList();
```

This is a simplified example. As you can imagine, when the object graph grows, this can be rather painful.

I just discovered AutoMapper, which looks like it will save me a lot of boilerplate code. When I want to send out a collection of Patient objects, which will be used in a grid in the client application, then I wouldn't want the full Patient object graph, I would want a simplified, flattened version. For that, a PatientDto class would be fine.

However, suppose I **do** want to send out the full object graph. I don't see any point in creating carbon copies of the Patient class, and all the related classes, then copying one to the other, just to be able to send them out. It would make more sense to reuse the EF-generated classes, and map the Patient object to a new Patient object, which (being created in code, not be EF) doesn't have the dynamic proxy. This is basically what my code above is doing.

I tried this, but I got the unhelpful and non-descriptive exception shown lower down.

Anyone any comments? Is this even a sensible thing to do? If not, what's the est way to handle this situation?

Here's the exception I got from the WCF test client when I tried to call the service using a mapping set up with `MapperConfiguration(c => c.CreateMap<Patient, Patient>())`

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:5448/PatientsService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Server stack trace:

> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at PatientsService.GetPatients()    at
>   PatientsServiceClient.GetPatients()

Inner Exception:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)

Inner Exception:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size)    at
>   System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean
>   userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

Inner Exception:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)

Comment: The question _"Why do we use Data Transfer Objects and not our entity classes when crossing layers"_ has been discussed to death. What did your research show, and do you want _that_ question answered, or do you want to solve the exception?

Comment: @CodeCaster Actually, I hadn't thought of it that way. I was thinking of the EF-generated classes as POCOs (which if you look at the code, they seem to be) with a proxy added on top when EF creates them. I was assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that when you create them yourself (as in `var p = new Patient()`) then you get the POCO without the proxy. From that point of view, it seemed pointless creating identical DTOs. Please can you clarify this, as I'm not sure where I'm thinking incorrectly.

Comment: @CodeCaster Any comment? How am i supposed to do this? Anyone able to comment?

Answer (score 1):

Your current issue seems to be your db connection was closed before you finisheds working with your data.

Try to use

```
db.mainEntity.Include(i=>i.relatedtable).Include(i=>i.anotherRelatedtable)
```

in your query for ALL related entities.

A good reason not to make a 1-to-1 copy of your objects in the serializer are loops (you probably had solved them before when using json-feeded components):

Father has children, and children has father, who has children, who has... overflow!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how does it help? All related entities are already loaded, so I'm not sure what using .Include() is going to add. My underlying problem (which wasn't what I was addressing in this question) is that the associated entities aren't being loaded until the connection has been closed. To avoid that, I would need to be able to tell the query which associated entities **not** to include. Please can you clarify.

Comment: If eager loading is enabled. entities will load related elements only when referenced. I haven tried that but, if your objects are in memory, I am not sure EF will assign child elements before you try to access them. Using "Include" should force those relationships to be updatedwhen you make the query. Of course, **you must ask the results before your connection closes**, so try ToList() on your result set before exiting your context's using statement or scope